# MySQL: IF EXISTS ... TRUNCATE

Tags: mysql

Want to truncate a table if it exists:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable') TRUNCATE mytable
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE
>   TABLE_NAME = 'mytable') ' at line 1

I tried also to add THEN after ) but the problems seems to be at IF.

Comment: You can only use IF in a function or procedure. See this for solutions with & without using a stored procedure : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801869/mysql-if-table-exists-truncate-and-insert-else-create

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need the two statements below to do that:

```
create table if not exists <mytable>;

truncate table <mytable>;
```

Comment: Is there no other solution?

Comment: yes it works but I wanted only to check if the table exists. The purpose was not to create the table if it does not exist

Comment: This will work, but a small overhead for CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  "ERROR 1113 (42000): A table must have at least 1 column"

Answer (score 3):

So I had a similar issue, and to resolve it, I created this procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `truncate_if_exist`$$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `truncate_if_exist`(IN tbl_name VARCHAR(150) )
  BEGIN
    IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_name = tbl_name AND table_schema = DATABASE()) THEN
    SET @query = CONCAT('TRUNCATE ', tbl_name);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
  END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

And then called it for each table that I wanted to truncate

for example:

```
CALL truncate_if_exist('users');
CALL truncate_if_exist('random_tmp_table');
```

Obviously, if the table does not exist, it will not run the `TRUNCATE` command.